# How to get the difference between two requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am creating a Bitcoin price checker.
Using the program it sends a request to Bitstamp's API link and gets the bitcoin $ price and prints it out.

I was wondering, how can I calculate the difference between the price in BTC

*Example*

> Bitcoin is $20 per coin
>
> Bitcoin is $25 per coin (+5)
>
> Bitcoin is $15 per coin (-10)

I have no idea how I'd do this or where to look, I've googled it but I haven't found anything working for me yet. (I am still a beginner)

The code:

```
import requests, json
from time import sleep

def getBitcoinPrice():
    URL = 'https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/'
    try:
        r = requests.get(URL)
        priceFloat = float(json.loads(r.text)['last'])
        return priceFloat
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print("Error querying Bitstamp API")

while True:
    print("BTC Price: $" + str(getBitcoinPrice()) + " per coin")
    sleep(60)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the previous price and compare it to the one you get each time you request the bitcoin API.

Here is a way you could do it :

```
import requests, json
from time import sleep

def getBitcoinPrice():
    URL = 'https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/'
    try:
        r = requests.get(URL)
        priceFloat = float(json.loads(r.text)['last'])
        return priceFloat
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print("Error querying Bitstamp API")

previous_price = 0
while True:
    bitcoin_price = getBitcoinPrice()
    print("BTC Price: ${} per coin ({})".format(bitcoin_price, bitcoin_price-previous_price))
    previous_price = bitcoin_price
    sleep(2)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help, I appreciate it alot.

Comment: If it solved your problem don't forget to accept an anwser. Here is the official SO [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you want to take a look

Comment: Completely forgot, I did now! Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

The previous price can be saved and the difference can be calculated after the first retrieval

```
import requests, json
from time import sleep

def getBitcoinPrice():
    URL = 'https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/'
    try:
        r = requests.get(URL)
        priceFloat = float(json.loads(r.text)['last'])
        return priceFloat
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print("Error querying Bitstamp API")

previous_price = None
while True:
    current_price = getBitcoinPrice()
    if not previous_price:  
        print("BTC Price: ${} per coin".format(current_price))
    else:
        print("BTC Price: ${} per coin ({})".format(current_price, current_price - previous_price))
    previous_price = current_price
    sleep(60)
```

Comment: Thank you alot for this!